# Clojure immutability practice

Tags: clojure

I´m trying to understand the Clojure´s immutability best practice and I have this simple example where I constantly re-declaring(updating) "new-orders" but I´m not sure if this is the right way.

```
(defrecord Order [fplate splate])

(def new-orders clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)

(defn add-order [orders order]
  (conj orders order))

(defn cook [order] ())

(defn cook-order [orders]
(cook (first orders)) (pop orders))

;;order1
(def o1 (->Order "Soup" "Fish&Chips"))
(def new-orders (add-order new-orders o1))

;;order2
(def o2 (->Order "Salad" "Hamburger"))
(def new-orders (add-order new-orders o2))

;;order3
(def o3 (->Order "Rice" "Steak"))
(def new-orders (add-order new-orders o3))

;;cook order
(def new-orders (cook-order new-orders))
(peek new-orders)
```

Thanks,
R.

Comment: Perhaps you could use atom https://clojure.org/reference/atoms? see this related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938330/clojure-swap-atom-dequeuing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more typical way of doing this example.  It uses the `spyx-pretty` function [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), but you could substitute `println` if you want:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(defrecord Order [fplate splate])

(def orders-queue (atom []))

(defn add-order [order]
  (swap! orders-queue conj order))

(defn cook [order] (println "cooking: " (pr-str order)))

(add-order (->Order "Soup" "Fish&Chips")) ; order1
(t/spyx-pretty orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Salad" "Hamburger")) ; order2
(t/spyx-pretty orders-queue)

(add-order (->Order "Rice" "Steak")) ; order3
(t/spyx-pretty orders-queue)

; cook orders
(newline)
(doseq [order @orders-queue]
  (cook order))
```

with results:

```
orders-queue => 
#<Atom@4147f771: [{:fplate "Soup", :splate "Fish&Chips"}]>

orders-queue => 
#<Atom@4147f771: 
  [{:fplate "Soup", :splate "Fish&Chips"}
   {:fplate "Salad", :splate "Hamburger"}]>

orders-queue => 
#<Atom@4147f771: 
  [{:fplate "Soup", :splate "Fish&Chips"}
   {:fplate "Salad", :splate "Hamburger"}
   {:fplate "Rice", :splate "Steak"}]>

cooking:  #tst.demo.core.Order{:fplate "Soup", :splate "Fish&Chips"}
cooking:  #tst.demo.core.Order{:fplate "Salad", :splate "Hamburger"}
cooking:  #tst.demo.core.Order{:fplate "Rice", :splate "Steak"}
```

Comment: This is certainly an improvement on the code in the question, although I would prefer to also see an explanation of how to actually do this functionally, since the question asks about immutability practice. One thing I don't get: what's this `demo.core` namespace you're importing in your `ns` clause? (I don't mind `tupelo` here, since you refer to it with `:as` and also explain how to use clojure.core instead)

Comment: I usually use the testing `ns` for demos, and forgot to delete unused  `:use` stuff. However, this answer doesn't have any unit tests and could have been in the main namespace.

Comment: Hi amalloy, Allan. Please correct me if I am wrong, but from your example and comments I understand that if I need to maintain and update the state of any kind of collection I can use atom and swap!. The questions was about immutability because by updating some collection I am mutating it and in this case is mandatory to maintain an dynamic list of orders. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, atom and swap! are one of the possibilities Clojure offers you. With swap! you are not directly modifying the state, rather you atomically substitute a new value for the state. You can calculate the new state from the previous state by doing something to the previous state (like a conj operation or something else). Atom and swap! is primitive in the sense it offers no protection for simultaneous transactional updates if you need something like that.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely is not the right way to do functional programming in Clojure, or any other FP language. Your code is still essentially imperative, though you have used Clojure as the implementation language.

The right way is to create new data structure with modified content whenever you need a new version of some data structure. Something like:

```
(let [a []
         b (conj a "order1")
         c (conj b "order2")]
     (println c))
```

In this case conj creates a new data structure by adding a new element to the structure given as parameter to conj. The old structure is not modified in any way, which means it's immutable.

If you really really need to have some sort of state, Clojure has primitives for that, like atom for example. But first try to write functional code without a modifiable central state.

Comment: Hi lokori, thanks for your answer. I understand your point. In a real world scenario( a restaurant) orders comes and goes constantly and there must be a point to keep the "actual-orders" so other functions like "prepare" or "update" must rely. What´s happens inside a let stays inside a let, so I guess this is something that I´m still missing. Thanks